# Remote Desktop limit to countries

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is it possible to limit Remote Desktop to some countries (and not just ips)

I am sure this is not some thing that is possible from within remote desktop but with some scripting. I dont want my remote desktop to be accesible from countries where I don't travel to or have any business with (which means any thing beyond Western or Northern Europe is probably not me)

I am asking this for Windows 2008 standard server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you look into some sort of VPN?

Operating on a non-standard port would also help, though security through obscurity is never terribly effective.

You could setup a firewall to block IPs from certain countries, but there's no way to guarantee where the originator of a packet it (they could us proxies or a myriad of other technologies).

Comment: +1 VPN. A whitelist is a lot easier to maintain than a blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only the way to block access to countries to guess their position with some geo-service.

If you want to secure your RDP you should use some kind of VPN. Blocking some countries sounds more like security through obscurity ;)